# How to do JavaScript alert in static method server side code in Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to do JavaScript alert in static method server side code in asp.net with C#. I tried many ways, but it's not working.

For example, I tried

```
[WebMethod]
public static void EntrySave(string schoolName)
{
      Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
}
```

and

```
[WebMethod]
public static void EntrySave(string schoolName)
{
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", 
       "alert('Only alert Message');", true);
}
```

and many more. But it's not showing alert in webstatic method.

Comment: How/where are you invoking the static method from ?

Comment: this static method I am invoking from ajax method which is calling from client side.

Comment: Please add [ScriptMethod] below [WebMethod] and try at once.

Comment: I tried @HardikLeuwa but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples may help you

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-receive-JavaScript-Array-to-Web-Service-Web-Method-using-ASP.Net-AJAX.aspx

[Response.Write() in WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550530/response-write-in-webservice/19868545)

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx. This url is work for me. Thank You. @Hardik Leuwa.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void EntrySave(string schoolName)
    {Response.Write("alert('Hello')");
}
```

More can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088842/using-alert-in-response-write-function-in-asp-net)

Comment: Mis Bhawna it is not working as per I tell you previously only. Infact at Response it is showing red underline.

Comment: can you attach a screen shot of error you are getting in your answer.?

Comment: got the solution. Thank You. Mis Bhawna for trying to solve my issue.

Comment: Hy Mis Bhawna please review this link......"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992714/undefined-coming-when-bind-gridview-using-ajax-in-c-sharp/44993886#44993886"